# Set up a quicker alias for `git push -u origin $BRANCH_NAME` and `git push` at the same time

Tags: git, git-push, git-alias

When I want to push changes on a branch that already has upstream branch, `git push` is all I need. But when there's no current upstream branch, I have to type out `git push -u $BRANCH_NAME`.

I create new branches all the time (for every feature that I work on, so it's about one every two hours or so). I also make typos sometimes. It gets irritating. How can I create an alias that would automatically resolve to `git push` or `git push -u $BRANCH_NAME` and wouldn't require me to type out branch name?

Comment: Besides [chelmertz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60877164/1256452), you can make an alias (pick some name for it) that runs `git push origin -u HEAD`. Your Git resolves the symbolic name `HEAD` to the current branch, so this works for any branch, after which the upstream is now set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get your wanted behavior, put this into your ~/.gitconfig:

```
[push]
    default = current
```

(as usual, `$ git config --global push.default current` does this for you.)

There's an explanation of the options of `push.default` here:

> **current** - push the current branch to update a branch with the same name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.
>
> -- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault

Comment: This is great, seriously, and I will use it but I'm still looking for a way to set an alias for a command that will set the upstream branch. Any ideas?

Comment: @LaurenceLord here's a guide on creating git aliases: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

If you want an alias in e.g. bash, you could add @torek's suggestion like this `alias gp="git push origin -u HEAD"` to ~/.bashrc